# ELF loader for Cortex-M processors

Tags: open-source, c

> **Note: before you say it, this is not a duplicate of [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34648/27945). I want a specific library.**

I want an ELF loader that can relocate PIC (Position Independent Code) on Cortex-M processors. There is no MMU and relocations on Thumb/Thumb-2 code are required. Traditional ARM won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
https://github.com/martinribelotta/elfloader

This is not a PIC/PIE solution but is library for load-in-time relocatable binary execution for ARMv7M (I have not test it on ARMv6M but I probably work)

Comment: i'm using ARMV7M (Cortex-M3) so that's not a problem, but do I need these `fopen()`, `close()`, `read()` functions? It would be nice to exec from a `char` array.

Comment: and if it isn't PIC/PIE then why are you relocating? I just need the relocation part, just want to know more about that.

Comment: You are free to define the correspondent macros.

Comment: Can I have a guide on how to do that (possibly in your answer)?

Comment: Question: Your char* program contain all ELF format? For relocate code you need to write code on relocation entries (described on metadata section of ELF).
This is true with relocatable code or PIC/PIE. The las method need GOT (global offset table) and PLT (Procedure Linkage table).
Even SYSV libraries (*.so) need GOT and PLT on RW area.

Comment: never mind, I got it to work. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I need your help now. I have declared at the beginning of my `.c` file a structure named `gui`. When your loader loads my code, it says `undefined symbol "gui". No symbol address found for "gui".` What have I done wrong?